# JSON.stringify of google map object

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

I am using DirectionsDisplay returned by Google Map JS APIv3 to get coordinates of some locations. The DirectionsDisplay has functions to return the values (`lat()` and `lng()`) but I need to send them to PHP serialized by `JSON.stringify` so I assign the values to new variables (`cLat` and `cLon`):

```
var steps=directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].steps;
for(var i=0;i<steps.length;i++){
  steps[i].end_location.cLat = steps[i].end_location.lat();
  steps[i].end_location.cLon = steps[i].end_location.lng();
}
```

`console.log(steps)` displays `cLat` and `cLon` as expected:

```
Object {steps: Array[8]}
  steps: Array[8]
    0: Object
      distance: Object
      duration: Object
      encoded_lat_lngs: "..."
      end_location: _.L
        cLat: 64.49756909999999    //here
        cLon: 14.148118999999951   //here
        lat: function()
        lng: function()
        __proto__: _.L
        ...
```

However, `console.log(JSON.stringify(steps))` displays this:

```
{
  "steps":[
    {
      "distance":{
        "text":"132 km",
        "value":132266
      },
      "duration":{
        "text":"1 hodín, 34 minút",
        "value":5639
      },
      "end_location":{
        "lat":64.49756909999999,    //here
        "lng":14.148118999999951    //here
      },

      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the relevant part from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js):

```
// If the value has a toJSON method, call it to obtain a replacement value.

    if (value && typeof value === 'object' &&
            typeof value.toJSON === 'function') {
        value = value.toJSON(key);
    }
```

`start_location` and `end_location` does have a method `toJSON`, so these properties will be set to the returnValue of this function in `JSON.stringify()`

One option would be to completely overwrite the `start_location` and `end_location`

```
for(var i=0;i<steps.length;i++){
  steps[i].end_location=    {
                             clat:steps[i].end_location.lat(),
                             cllng:steps[i].end_location.lng()
                            };
  steps[i].start_location=  {
                             clat:steps[i].start_location.lat(),
                             clng:steps[i].start_location.lng()
                            };

  steps[i].end_location.cLon = steps[i].end_location.lng();
}
```

But there is no need to to this(there also may be issues when the API needs to access these properties again).

As you see in the stringified `steps` they already contain the desired informations (`lat` and `lng`), just use them in your PHP-script instead of your custom properties.